# How to compare a datetime to a datetime + X hours with PHP?

Tags: php, date, datetime

I got 2 datetimes objects. One is the current datetime. The otherone is when the user Checked in. To which I'd like to add 6 hours.

I first initialize the current datetime:

```
$now=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

Then I'm using datediff but I don't now how to add 6 hours, I assume I would have to use modify, but i don't understand how to use it.

```
 $datetimeIn = date_create($result->getDateCheckIn());

   $datetimeOut = date_create($now);
    date_modify($datetimeOut, '+6 hours');
    $interval = date_diff($datetimeIn, $datetimeOut);
    if ($interval->format('%a minute') > 0)
        $UsersToCheckOut[] = $result;
```

Can somebody help me figuring howw to add X hours to a datetime to compare it to another ?

I got this error:
date_create() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in line date_modify($datetimeOut, '+6 hours');

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to attempt to answer both your title and the question I inferred you were asking from the body of your question.

The PHP manual is very clear on actually comparing datetimes. Here's example code for that:

```
$date1 = new DateTime("now");
$date2 = new DateTime("+6 hours");

var_dump($date1 == $date2);
var_dump($date1 < $date2);
var_dump($date1 > $date2);

//bool(false)
//bool(true)
//bool(false)
```

The part where you actually add 6 hours is also correct. I copied your code and tested it see if I could get the same error as you. I did when my $datetimeIn parameter was bad. Based off that and the error you posted, it looks very much like the problem lies in your $datetimeIn parameter. I copied my working code below:

```
$now=date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('2013-04-15 04:00:0'));

$datetimeIn = date_create($now);
$datetimeOut = date_create($now);
date_modify($datetimeOut, '+6 hours');
$interval = date_diff($datetimeIn, $datetimeOut);

if ($interval->format('%a minute') > 0) {
    echo "success";     
} else {
    echo "fail";
}
```

According to the error message, it is happening because in your line "$datetimeOut = date_create($now);", the variable $now exists and is some kind of object; date_create() requires the first argument to be some kind of string. See documentation about the valid date and time formats [here](http://php.net/datetime.formats)

Comment: It's polite to explain why you downvoted someone. We're all here to learn, so if you tell me what I did wrong, I can avoid the error in the future.

Comment: I didn't down vote you, but I suspect it was because you don't actually answer the question. You show some similar code and state it doesn't generate any errors, then ask a question. It is not clear that you are offering a solution. As it stands, this is likely to be flagged as 'not an answer'. If you want more information from the OP, then use a comment to ask. See [How to Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I will edit my comment to make what I'm trying to say more clear.

Comment: I meant edit my answer (which I have done.) Thanks again for the comment. I read through the How to Answer guide.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a copy, with an offset of 6 hours, like this:

```
$now    = date_create('now');
$future = date_modify(clone $now, '+ 6 hours');
$diff   = date_diff($now, $future);
var_dump($diff);die;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$datetimein =  date("m/d/Y H:i:s");
$datetimeout = date("m/d/Y H:i:s", strtotime($datetimein) + 6 * 60 * 60);
```

see it working live: http://codepad.viper-7.com/6wn8dK

Comment: The OP states that he's working with DateTime objects rather than strings, so something like [this](http://codepad.viper-7.com/5pgIgB) would probably have been more relevant.